# How to get whole scroll event when removing element from adapter of recyclerview?

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create "sticky headers" on a RecyclerView (which uses a LinearLayoutManager) but now I'm facing a problem. When I click on one item of the list, a new item is automatically inserted just below it and the RecyclerView's default animation is shown (the one which smoothly adds and shows the new item). When I tap the initial item again, this new added item is removed, and the RecyclerView's default animation is shown again (the one to slowly hide the removed item).

I have completed all the sticky headers functionality but now my problem is that when I click the last list item and the hide default animation is shown (with a scroll up), my sticky headers don't work. I need to know (and here is were I'm stuck) how to get notified while this RecyclerView animation is being performed when adding/removing items. I need to get notified with all the animation steps, not only the start and end ones.

So far I've tried to use a RecyclerView onScrollListener and a ViewTreeObserver (attached to the added/removed view) but neither worked. If someone could give me some help, it would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance to all the Stack Overflow community